# I have used Oracle10gDialect but i am getting error

Tags: java, hibernate

HTTP Status 500 - `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect.registerColumnType(IJLjava/lang/String;)`

type Exception report

message `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect.registerColumnType(IJLjava/lang/String;)`

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect.registerColumnType(IJLjava/lang/String;)V
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:256)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    us.ny.state.dcjs.dir.client.filter.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:66)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect.registerColumnType(IJLjava/lang/String;)V
    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect.registerCharacterTypeMappings(Oracle9iDialect.java:43)
    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect.<init>(Oracle8iDialect.java:59)
    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect.<init>(Oracle9iDialect.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:78)
    org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:42)
    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:422)
    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    us.ny.state.dcjs.dir.client.session.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    us.ny.state.dcjs.dir.client.session.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    us.ny.state.dcjs.dir.client.pagecode.DIRUploadMetaDataWImageView.testDatabase(DIRUploadMetaDataWImageView.java:1920)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:70)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:95)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:450)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:759)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    us.ny.state.dcjs.dir.client.filter.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:66)
```

Comment: Always format your code/exception properly so that others can understand it instead of figuring out what it could be.

Comment: Sorry for that.. can you please help me in this.. what is this error !!

Comment: What's your maven config or classpath? It seems your libraries are in conflict.

Comment: Could be old version or multiple jars of the same are present in the classpath.

Comment: Somehow its been resolved... by changing the cglib.jar version 2.2 to 2.1.. and Oracle10gDialect to OracleDialect..

Answer (score 3):

Better to check your **hibernate-core** version and other hibernate related jar files version all should be same other wise if you are using one jar from 4.x and another from 3.x then these dialect related issues will come.